# How to install unity 8 with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity8

I don't want to update 16.10 so is there anyway for me to install the Unity 8 version which is currently shipped with 16.10?

**Edit**: I tried installing it through [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-unity-8-desktop-progress-video) quite a while ago but it lacks a lot of things, so I switched back to Unity 7

Comment: 16.10 ships with Unity 7 and a Unity 8 preview. Hence, what do you mean by "I don't want the preview version"? https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/10/13/unity-8-preview-session-in-ubuntu-16-10-yakkety-yak/

Comment: I didn't know that its also called preview version. The thing is I installed the "Unity 8 desktop mir" around 6 months ago and its just like a trial version. Now when  it is officially released with 16.10 (hopefully with all featured supported) I wanna try it again but don't know how.

Comment: unity8 is still quite useless in 16.10 so don't bother. It may be a bit better in 17.04

Comment: Is that so? thanks for the information, guess I will wait then :)

Comment: @user3313023 The Unity 8 version bundled with 16.10 is the same as the `unity8-desktop-session-mir` you may or may not have installed in 16.04.